# DisplayTag doesn't work inside a forEach tag

Tags: jsp, jstl, displaytag

I'm trying to render a DisplayTag table inside a forEach loop. The expression `${paquete.listaProductoPaquete}` is a one item list; but when I try this I get an empty table:

```
<c:forEach var="paquete"
    items="${consultaConsumosWrapper.listadoPaqueteConsumo}">
    <tr>
        <td><display:table
                name="${paquete.listaProductoPaquete}" export="false"
                id="producto" style="width:100%" sort="list"
                defaultsort="1" class="grilla">
                <display:column sortable="false"
                    titleKey="header.consultaDatos.producto">
                    ${producto.producto}
                </display:column>
            </display:table> 
            </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

If I try this, I get the information of the single item on the list as expected:

```
<c:forEach var="paquete"
    items="${consultaConsumosWrapper.listadoPaqueteConsumo}">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <c:forEach var="producto"
                items="${paquete.listaProductoPaquete}">
                ${producto.producto}
            </c:forEach></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working? When I try the tag outside a loop anything goes normal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to
`<display:table name="paquete.listaProductoPaquete" ...`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure, you are using displayTag with EL support. In your DisplayTag jar file, you should have displayTag-el.tld file.

If you List has correct data, you should see the table for following code: I just removed DisplayColumn and sort attributes from displayTable tag.

```
<c:forEach var="paquete"
    items="${consultaConsumosWrapper.listadoPaqueteConsumo}">
    <tr>
        <td><display:table
                name="${paquete.listaProductoPaquete}" export="false"
                style="width:100%" class="grilla">                    
            </display:table> 
         </td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```